# Why do I get ORA-06531: reference to uninitialized collection?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I want to call a PL/SQL function with

```
select consult_trac.get_detail_dos_amo('12345') from dual
```

but I get the error:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06530: Reference to uninitialized composite
> ORA-06512: à "CNSS_SERVICES.GET_DETAIL_DOS_AMO" at line 60 (ret(v_counter).num_doss := DS_DT.NUM_DOSS;)

My PL/SQL function is defined in a package with all the types.

Package definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE consult_trac AS

FUNCTION get_detail_dos_amo (p_num_doss VARCHAR2)
      RETURN tab_dos_t_amo;

END consult_trac;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY consult_trac AS
    FUNCTION get_detail_dos_amo (p_num_doss VARCHAR2)
      RETURN tab_dos_t_amo
      IS
      CURSOR DOSS_DET (num_doss VARCHAR2) IS
        SELECT NUM_DOSS,
               DAT_DEP,
               NUM_IMMA,
               NUM_IND,
               P_DATE_ACTE,
               CODE_EVOP,
               LIB_EVOP,
               CODE_DR,
               LIB_DR,
               C_USER,
               C_GENCE,
               C_NIV,
               L_NIV,
               DAT_SUI,
               C_D_ETAT,
               L_D_ETAT,
               L_NAT,
               NUM_RECOM,
               ACCUSE,
               P_MONTANT,
               NUM_D_PARENT,
               P_INP_DOS,
               P_ICE_DOS,
               P_CIN,
               P_NOM,
               P_PRENOM,
               P_N_PAGE,
               P_D_SORTIE,
               P_C_CAT,
               P_C_SOURCE,
               C_ERROR
        FROM   TYP_DOSS_AMO
        WHERE  NUM_DOSS = p_num_doss;
      
      CURSOR SEL_MEDIC(num_doss   VARCHAR2) IS
        SELECT CODE_MEDIC, 
               NOMBRE 
        FROM DOSS_MEDIC
        WHERE NUM_DOSS = num_doss;
      
      CURSOR SEL_INP(num_doss   VARCHAR2) IS
        SELECT CODE_INP
        FROM DOSS_INP
        WHERE NUM_DOSS = num_doss;
        
      ret tab_dos_t_amo;
      ret_med tab_medic; 
      ret_inp tab_inp;
      v_counter number := 0;
      v_counter_med number := 0;
      v_counter_inp number := 0;
    BEGIN
      FOR DS_DT IN DOSS_DET(p_num_doss) 
            LOOP
                ret(v_counter).num_doss := DS_DT.NUM_DOSS;
                ret(v_counter).dat_dep := DS_DT.DAT_DEP;
                ret(v_counter).num_imma := DS_DT.NUM_IMMA;
                ret(v_counter).num_ind := DS_DT.NUM_IND;
                ret(v_counter).p_date_acte := DS_DT.P_DATE_ACTE;
                ret(v_counter).code_evop := DS_DT.CODE_EVOP;
                ret(v_counter).lib_evop := DS_DT.LIB_EVOP;
                ret(v_counter).code_dr := DS_DT.CODE_DR;
                ret(v_counter).lib_dr := DS_DT.LIB_DR;
                ret(v_counter).c_user := DS_DT.C_USER;
                ret(v_counter).c_gence := DS_DT.C_GENCE;
                ret(v_counter).c_niv := DS_DT.C_NIV;
                ret(v_counter).l_niv := DS_DT.L_NIV;
                ret(v_counter).dat_sui := DS_DT.DAT_SUI;
                ret(v_counter).c_d_etat := DS_DT.C_D_ETAT;
                ret(v_counter).l_d_etat := DS_DT.L_D_ETAT;
                ret(v_counter).l_nat := DS_DT.L_NAT;
                ret(v_counter).num_recom := DS_DT.NUM_RECOM;                
                ret(v_counter).accuse := DS_DT.ACCUSE;  
                ret(v_counter).p_montant := DS_DT.P_MONTANT;
                ret(v_counter).num_d_parent := DS_DT.NUM_D_PARENT;
                ret(v_counter).p_INP_dos := DS_DT.P_INP_DOS;
                ret(v_counter).p_ICE_dos := DS_DT.P_ICE_DOS;
                ret(v_counter).p_cin := DS_DT.P_CIN;
                ret(v_counter).p_nom := DS_DT.P_NOM;
                ret(v_counter).p_prenom := DS_DT.P_PRENOM;
                ret(v_counter).p_n_page := DS_DT.P_N_PAGE;
                ret(v_counter).p_d_sortie := DS_DT.P_D_SORTIE;
                ret(v_counter).p_c_cat := DS_DT.P_C_CAT;
                ret(v_counter).p_c_source := DS_DT.P_C_SOURCE;
                ret(v_counter).c_error := DS_DT.C_ERROR;
                
                FOR SM IN SEL_MEDIC(p_num_doss)
                    LOOP
                        ret_med(v_counter_med).code_medic := SM.CODE_MEDIC;
                        ret_med(v_counter_med).nombre := SM.NOMBRE;
                        v_counter_med := v_counter_med +1;
                    END LOOP;
                FOR SI IN SEL_INP(p_num_doss)
                    LOOP
                        ret_inp(v_counter_inp).code_inp := SI.CODE_INP;
                        v_counter_inp := v_counter_inp +1;
                    END LOOP;
                ret(v_counter).p_tab_medic := ret_med;
                ret(v_counter).p_tab_inp := ret_inp;
                v_counter := v_counter + 1;
            END LOOP;

        return ret;
    END;
   
END consult_trac;
/
```

Types:

```
create or replace TYPE MEDIC AS OBJECT (
    num_doss   VARCHAR2(9),
    code_medic VARCHAR2(10),
    nombre     NUMBER);

create or replace TYPE tab_medic IS TABLE OF MEDIC;

create or replace TYPE INP AS OBJECT (
    num_doss   VARCHAR2(9),
    code_inp   VARCHAR2(20));

create or replace TYPE tab_INP IS TABLE OF INP;

create or replace TYPE TYP_DOS_AMO AS OBJECT (
        num_doss   VARCHAR2(9),
        dat_dep    DATE,
        num_imma   VARCHAR2(13),
        num_ind    VARCHAR2(20),
        p_date_acte  DATE,
        code_evop  VARCHAR2(20),
        lib_evop   VARCHAR2(30),
        code_dr    VARCHAR2(20),
        lib_dr     VARCHAR2(30),
        c_user     VARCHAR2(20),
        c_gence    VARCHAR2(20),
        c_niv      VARCHAR2(20),
        l_niv      VARCHAR2(20),
        dat_sui    DATE,
        c_d_etat   VARCHAR2(20),
        l_d_etat   VARCHAR2(20),
        l_nat      VARCHAR2(30),
        num_recom  VARCHAR2(30),
        accuse     VARCHAR2(30),
        p_montant  VARCHAR2(20),
        num_d_parent VARCHAR2(9),
        p_INP_dos  VARCHAR2(20),
        p_ICE_dos  VARCHAR2(20),
        p_cin      VARCHAR2(10),
        p_nom      VARCHAR2(20),
        p_prenom   VARCHAR2(20),
        p_n_page   VARCHAR2(20),              
        p_d_sortie DATE,
        p_c_cat    VARCHAR2(15),
        p_c_source VARCHAR2(15),
        p_tab_medic tab_medic,
        p_tab_inp   tab_inp,
        c_error    INTEGER
);
    
create or replace TYPE tab_INP IS TABLE OF INP;
```

Comment: the complete trace error is: 06531. 00000 -  "Reference to uninitialized collection"
*Cause:    An element or member function of a nested table or varray
           was referenced (where an initialized collection is needed)
           without the collection having been initialized.
*Action:   Initialize the collection with an appropriate constructor
           or whole-object assignment.

Comment: Where are these types located ? In the first cursor from clause `typ_dos_amo` a table ?

Comment: they are located in schema level. typ_dos_amo is a type

Comment: You posted the definition of `typ_dos_amo` above and it's a PL/SQL record: `TYPE typ_dos_amo IS RECORD`. It must be in a package, although you don't say which package. There is also a table named `typ_doss_amo`.

Comment: Types were defined in the consult_trac package, but i removed the definition from there and put them at schema level. typ_dos_amo is a type whereas typ_doss_amo is a table

Comment: You should mention it then clearly because implementation of both types would be different. Are you sure you have created a table and  an object with same name ?

Comment: it's note the same name typ_dos_amo and typ_doss_amo

Comment: Did you find some solution ? I have one but with not actual data as in your package.

Comment: How is the type `tab_dos_t_amo` defined?

Comment: Connor McDonald's answer fixes the object initialisation issue. You'll also need to review the queries with `where num_doss = num_doss`, as they will return all rows when you only want one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A nested table object is not the same as an associative array, so it must be initialised before usage.

Thus

```
ret tab_dos_t_amo
```

probably needs to be

```
ret tab_dos_t_amo := tab_dos_t_amo();
```

Now as you want to add elements to it, you need to add an index to the array, for example

```
ret.extend;
```

which now allows you to reference ret(1).

You didn't show us the definition for tab_dos_t_amo but I assume it is a table of dos_t_amo.  So each entry in that table is an object, which means your code:

```
            ret(v_counter).num_doss := DS_DT.NUM_DOSS;
            ret(v_counter).dat_dep := DS_DT.DAT_DEP;
            ret(v_counter).num_imma := DS_DT.NUM_IMMA;
```

would now look like

```
            ret.extend;
            ret(v_counter) := dos_t_amo(
                                  DS_DT.DAT_DEP,
                                  DS_DT.NUM_IMMA,
                                  ...
                                  ...);
```

Comment: I am also getting same error although i have initialized array like above. also i am getting error intermittently. type look like : create or replace TYPE          T_TABLE_TYPE1 AS TABLE OF T_TYPE2; and using it in stored procedure like : V_DATA T_TABLE_TYPE1      := T_TABLE_TYPE1(); SELECT V_DATA(1).field1 into field_data;